# Automatically add braces after underscore or caret in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter

Is there any option for adding automatically braces after `_` or `^` in TeXnicCenter?

Comment: @dustin, braces = curly brackets, I believe your edit to be redundant, and I'm changing it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using TeXnicCenter for quite a while and I haven't seen that feature.  However, you can send a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/feature-requests/) to the developers.

Also, as a workaround, you could use an external program to have it set, such as Robotype.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Kile because for everything you can define keyboard shortcuts. There's a feature in Kile called User Tags (LaTeX->Edit User Tags) that allow you to insert small or big portions of code in your document just with a keyboard shortcut.

Check this site out: http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/extragear-office/kile/latex_usertags.html

Kile can be installed in Windows too: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/kile/index.php?title=KileOnWindows

Best regards!